# Updating Azure Batch autoscale formula once pool exists

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-batch

I can create a pool with an autoscale formula fine. The code for this is as follows.

```
var pool = client.PoolOperations.CreatePool(poolName, vmsize, new CloudServiceConfiguration(osFamily, osVersion));
pool.TaskSchedulingPolicy = new TaskSchedulingPolicy(ComputeNodeFillType.Pack);
pool.AutoScaleFormula = autoscaleFormula;
pool.AutoScaleEnabled = true;
pool.AutoScaleEvaluationInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0);
pool.Commit();
```

However if once the pool exists, I try and update the AutoScale formula, I get an error. The error is

> {"The property AutoScaleFormula cannot be modified while the object is
>   in the Bound state."}

The code is

```
var client = BatchClient.Open(GetCloudSharedKeyCredentials(primary));
var pool = client.PoolOperations.GetPool(poolName);      
pool.AutoScaleFormula = formula;
pool.AutoScaleEnabled = true;
pool.AutoScaleEvaluationInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0);
pool.Commit();
```

This used to work before I updated to the latest version of the Azure Batch library. Has anyone got any experience of Azure Batch and can advise why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PoolOperations.EnableAutoScale method directly.
For your example, you could use the following:

```
var client = BatchClient.Open(GetCloudSharedKeyCredentials(primary));
client.Pooloperations.EnableAutoScale(poolName, formula, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
```